# Properties file vs environment variable

Tags: java

Hey i wondered what is the difference between `.properties` file to `environment variable` in `java`.
**.Properties file**

```
arg1=text1

arg2=text2
```

**environment variable**

```
java -jar -arg1=text1 -arg2=text2 myJAR.jar
```

Comment: Looks like you already know the difference between the two.

Comment: To assign at the command line you would need to use -D. If you got lots of properties then it will be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arguments in this way is not overridable at runtime :

```
java -jar -arg1=text1 -arg2=text2 myJAR.jar
```

as the values are passed when the application is started.

You have to restart the application to change the values.
Besides, passing a lot of arguments may be error prone.

Valuing properties in this way may be overridable at runtime  :

```
.Properties file 
arg1=text1 
arg2=text2
```

As the values are located in a external file that may be modified during the runtime of the application. Of course a way foreseen to take into consideration the file modification during the runtime has to be implemented in the application.
For example, Logback (with Joran implementation) provides a way 
to change the Logback configuration file at runtime :
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are `key-value` pairs passed to a program while it's invoked whereas `properties` file consists of list of properties along with their values. Generally, properties file is considered to be the best practice to maintain configuration values, here's why:

- Properties file are more readable than environment variables. Also, they are not tied to startup script, we can pass any file while running the program.
- Frameworks like `Spring` provide different ways to create a `collection` or `map` from properties file.
- It's easy to use different `properties` files for different environments (e.g. stage, prod etc)